# Падение Imagick

Tags: imagick, wamp

Поставил Imagick вот отсюда http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/imagick/ ставил последнюю версию `3.4.3rc4`.

Скачал архив `php_imagick-3.4.3rc4-7.1-ts-vc14-x64.zip`. Файл php_imagick.dll закинул в `PHP\extensions`, файлы `CORE_RL_*.dll` в `Apache\bin`. В `php.ini` добавил новое расширение. Перезапустил сервер. `phpinfo()` выдал

```
imagick module version   | 3.4.3RC4
imagick classes          | Imagick, ImagickDraw, ImagickPixel, ImagickPixelIterator, ImagickKernel
ImageMagick release date | 2016-03-27
```

Далее пишу код

```
$img = new Imagick();
$img->readImage('D:/Test/444.bmp');
```

и на второй строчке падает процесс апача. В системном логе Windows запись

> Имя сбойного приложения: httpd.exe, версия: 2.4.25.0, метка времени: 0x5854e3d6
>   Имя сбойного модуля: php_imagick.dll, версия: 7.1.0.0, метка времени: 0x5889303b
>   Код исключения: 0xc0000409
>   Смещение ошибки: 0x0000000000023c9c
>   Идентификатор сбойного процесса: 0x1014
>   Время запуска сбойного приложения: 0x01d2b9e44bda4cae
>   Путь сбойного приложения: C:\Program Files\WebServer\Apache\Apache24\bin\httpd.exe
>   Путь сбойного модуля: C:\Program Files\WebServer\PHP\ext\php_imagick.dll
>   Идентификатор отчета: 8d81efe5-25d7-11e7-81aa-0018f3748b6f
>   Полное имя сбойного пакета:
>   Код приложения, связанного со сбойным пакетом:

Что я делаю не так?

**UPDATE**

Смущают еще такие строки в `phpifo()`

```
ImageMagick number of supported formats: |  0
ImageMagick supported formats            |
```

Comment: Под NT эта dll может и не пойти. Попробуйте Imagick portable version, а dll при этом лучше удалить.

Comment: Может еще поэтому: If you have any problems, you likely need vcomp120.dll. To install it, download Visual C++ 2013 Redistributable Package. https://www.imagemagick.org/script/binary-releases.php

Comment: а зачем вы качаете `RC` при наличии релизной версии?

Comment: @labris Какая NT? Я же написал Windows 8 Enterprise Edition. vcomp120.dll лежит в System32

Comment: @teran RC качаю, потому, что такая версия стоит на хостинге

Comment: @teran Поставил 3.4.3 - ничего не изменилось

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скачал отсюда http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/deps/ `ImageMagick-6.9.3-7-vc14-x64.zip` (в архиве ImageMagick-7.0.5-4-portable-Q16-x64.zip не было dll, а dll, которые лежали в инсталляции `ImageMagick-7.0.5-4-Q16-x64-dll.exe` ничего не изменили), закинул все dll в папку `Apache\bin` и перезапустил апач. После этого phpinfo сообщил, что поддерживаются 234 формата и все заработало.

Наверное не совсем правильно валить сервер, вместо того, чтобы выбросить исключение `Format not supported`